# Doctor told me to take Absolut vodka as pain reliever, is it haram?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, medical

I have a metal plate in my arm that was caused by a car bombing. I started taking tramadol to relief my pain but i got into an addiction problem with it so later i stopped. The doctor then told me about Absolut vodka and he said that it was intended to be a medicine/drug that could be used medically but then they just sold it was vodka, he also said that it has 0% of addiction.

Should i take it for my severe pain or is it haram?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Is this doctor a Muslim? You always have the right to ask for a second opinion (go to an other physician for example) and you should tell that alcohol consummation is an issue for you and you would only do so if there's no other option.

Comment: @medi1saif he's not a muslim, and he did mention that Muslims can't take it because it is haram but I told him that i might be able to take it if it was initially made to be a medicine. I can't go to another doctor cause I'm getting medication abroad and I was assigned to this doctor by my country's agency here.

Comment: There’s a Du’a in which you can ask the best doctor there is to heal you up, and there is no need for you to implement the advice given by this doctor you went.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can necessary medication be permissible even if it contains haram ingredients?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35622/can-necessary-medication-be-permissible-even-if-it-contains-haram-ingredients)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In the Quran,Our Holy Prophet  Hazrat Muhammad P.B.u.h said if a huge amount of drugs are you going to insane, its minimum amount are haram. but on the other hand Doctor said to you that you take it small amount, being a Muslim you completely disobey the Doctors advice because it is totals against the teaching of Islam.

Comment: Are u saying that it's okay to take small amounts or is it not??

Comment: small amount too is prohibited, completely deny of taking drugs.

Comment: This is a hadith not from the Quran. Also it is a rather poor paraphrasing of the hadith, it talks about intoxication not insanity.

Answer (score 1):

Even from a secular, non-Muslim perspective, this is very bad advice for everyone, regardless of their religion.
And under Islam, it becomes even worse.

> The doctor then told me about Absolut vodka and he said that it was intended to be a medicine/drug that could be used medically [to relieve pain].

This is partially true.

- Alcohol dulls the senses, and it also makes one artificially happy and not care about the pain that one still feels.
  So yes, it would temporarily relieve the pain.
- Before general anesthetics were invented, surgeons often gave their patients large doses of "medicinal whisky" before the operation.
  Even if it didn't cause unconsciousness, it numbed the feeling of pain and kept the patient still and quiet enough that the surgery could be performed.
  Without it, the patient would almost certainly die (so I suspect that this would be an acceptable practice as preservation of life is more important than a single instance of a minor sin).

But:

- It would make no difference which brand of vodka (or any other form of alcoholic drink) is used.
  Alcohol is alcohol.
- The above surgical example was a one-time use for one specific situation, not perpetual daily use.
- Taking alcohol for pain is not a cure, and it provides only temporary relief.
- One's body becomes habituated to the drug, and so larger and more frequent doses will be required.
- Taking alcohol for chronic pain would require being perpetually drunk for the rest of one's life.
- Side effects of long-term alcohol use include damage to the liver, and possibly triggering various forms of cancer.

> he also said that it has 0% of addiction.

This is totally wrong:

- Calling something medicine doesn't change what it is made of.
  (["*A rose by any other name would smell as sweet*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet#:%7E:text=%22A%20rose%20by%20any%20other,affect%20what%20they%20really%20are.))
- Alcohol is very physically addictive for some people (alcoholism).
- Used as prescribed here, the alcohol would be very mentally addictive for everyone.

If I were in this situation, and nothing could be done about the actual cause of the pain, I'd seek non-physical help that would allow my mind to ignore the pain most of the time.
E.g. non-religious meditation, psychiatry, or one's religious teachers come to mind.