# Can we apply 'Minoxidil' on scalp or face to get proper scalp or beard hair?

Tags: halal-haram

Minoxidil contains alcohol (synthetic), also we r not consuming, just applying. So, is it allowed? Some people say that because it is synthetic alcohol which is made by chemical, not natural alcohol, so it is OK. Also, we are not consuming, we are just applying on body, so it is fine. Other people say that even though it is synthetic and we are just applying, still it is haraam, and also by trying to modify your looks by doing this, you are Nauzubillah challenging Allah that I do not like the way you have made me and I am changing it. So it is not allowed. Can you please let us know whether this is allowed or no?

Comment: Alcohol is najis.

Comment: So that means if we apply, then we have to do ghusl necessarily before performing any Namaz? Also, even if we assume that the alcohol in it is not synthetic, it is the actual toxic alcohol that is used to consume, then also it will be the same thing as above?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The following points should be kept in mind:

- Alcohol is distinct from Ethanol which is distinct from Wine. Alcohol a genus in Chemistry for all chemicals which have the -OH group. Ethanol is a specific type of alcohol which causes intoxication, which can be produced by fermentation of sugars or synthetically. Wine is a beverage produced by fermentation of fruit, which contains ethanol as its essence.

  According to some madhabs (Hanafis) it is Wine (produced from grapes or dates) that is unclean and forbidden for use, not ethanol - they would allow for use of ethanol obtained from other than Wine as long as it does not cause intoxication.  Mioxidil does not contain wine, and its topical use does not lead to intoxication.

  Further, other alcohols like Isopropanol or Methanol or Propylene glycol , do not have the same ruling as Ethanol as they are a different substance with different properties. Minoxidil preparations may contain any one or more of them.
- Using Wine or another haram substance as medicine remains forbidden. See [Can necessary medication be permissible even if it contains haram ingredients?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35622/)
- There might be other alternates available to Minoxidil, such as hormonal treatment or the use of Finasteride or Dutasteride. It might also be possible to obtain minoxidil that is free from ethanol. You can ask your doctor to suggest any alternates.

Answer (score 0):

if the alcohol is ethanol alcohol made through brewing then no, but if its isopropyl or rubbing alcohol then its ok

Comment: Would it be possible to [edit] in some reliable references please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply 'Minoxidil' on your sculp or face to grow hairs, if you have been affected by hairfall or beard fall. Hairfall and bearfall are sickness'. According to Muhammad's (Peace Be Upon Him) lifestyle and hadith, using medicine is halal and 'Minoxidil' plays the role of medicine of hairfall and beard-fall. And when using urine to make medicine is allowed, why wouldn't it be allowed to make medicine with alcohol?

> Anas (R) said, "Some people of 'Ukl or 'Uraina tribe came to Medina and its climate did not suit them. So the Prophet (pbuh) ordered them to go to the herd of (Milch) camels and to drink their milk and urine (as a medicine). [Al-bukhari, 233]

So, it is halal, according to my knowledge.

*Every answer can be wrong in this forum, so Please consider asking this question to a mufti. Don't rely on this answer.*

Answer (score -1):

Alcohol was once used to sanitise and cleanse an area of the arm before using a hypodermic needle there.

It's less often used that way. This is no way is against Islam as the patient is not being asked to drink it. It's merely being used for the purposes for hygiene.

Similarly for the situation you have outlined.